# How to add shell script to all jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I want to add "git tag" script to all jenkins jobs, and I know how to add the script to one specific job. But is there a way to add this script globally for every job?

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/${project}
prefix="btag"
if [[ "$buildtype" = "Release" || "$buildtype" = "FirstPublish" ]];then
    prefix="rtag"
fi
tag=`date "+$prefix-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-${BUILD_USER}"`
git tag $tag
git push origin $tag
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of articles out there that describe how to update multiple jobs at once. Jenkin's Groovy script console respectively API helps you.

You "just" have to iterate over `Hudson.instance.items`, which represents your jobs.

Example articles are [Mastering Jenkins: Making Bulk Updates to Jobs](https://earlyandoften.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/mastering-jenkins-making-bulk-updates-to-jobs/) and [in the Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Add+notification+plugin+to+every+job).

Other options include batch-editing the jobs' XML files.